# positioning even and odd in css

Tags: html, css

I'm very desperate. I have problems with one code what I want to use. First of all there is screenshots:

NEW SCREENSHOT with Zeta's help. It's better now, but still spaces at some items:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28372149/gasps.jpg

You see those spaces between items. I don't want to help with corners and points cause its my graphic fault and I will gonna repair that, but big issue is those spaces.

html:

```
<ol id="timeline">

<li>
    <div class="time">2.1.2012</div>
    <span class="corner"></span>
        <p style="text-align: left">
        V Česku bylo místy tepleji než v Řecku.
        <a href="http://www.novinky.cz/domaci/255046-v-cesku-bylo-misty-tepleji-nez-v-recku.html">
        CELÁ ZPRÁVA
        </a>
        </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="time">1.1.2012</div>
    <span class="corner"></span>
            <p style="text-align: left">
                <strong>Češi věznění v Zambii jsou doma, ze země odjeli při utajené akci.</strong>
                </br>
                <img align="centre" src="foto/leden/1.jpg"></br>Češi věznění v Zambii jsou doma, ze země odjeli při utajené akci. Trojice mužů obviněná
                tamními úřady ze špionáže se dostala domů ke konci roku, pravděpodobně po zásahu českých úřadů. Ty zambijské akci se špionážními prvky odsoudily.
                <a href="http://www.novinky.cz/domaci/254926-cesi-vezneni-v-zambii-jsou-doma-ze-zeme-odjeli-pri-utajene-akci.html">
                CELÁ ZPRÁVA
                </a>
                </p>
  </li>
```

css:

```css
time,.time{
    font-size: 12px; color:gray; border-bottom: 1px solid #8b130e; min-width:350px; height:15px; padding-bottom: 1px;
}
#timeline{
    width:800px; list-style-type: none; background: url(timeline.png) top center repeat-y; margin: 0 auto; padding:20px; margin-bottom:10px;
}

#timeline li{
    width:375px; -moz-border-radius:2px; border-radius:2px; webkit-border-radius:2px; border:2px solid #d56560; padding:5px;background-color:#FFF;
}

#timeline li:nth-of-type(odd){
clear: right;float:both;float:right
}
#timeline li:nth-of-type(even){
clear: left;float:both;float:left
}
#timeline li:nth-of-type(odd), #timeline li:nth-of-type(even){
    margin:-10px 0 20px 0;
}
#timeline li:nth-of-type(even) .corner{
        position:absolute; display:block; margin-left:380px;width:20px; height:15px;background:url(right.png);
}
#timeline li:nth-of-type(odd) .corner{
        position:absolute;display:block;margin-left:-25px;width:20px;height:15px;background:url(left.png);
}
```

Can someone really help me with it? I will be so happy :)

Comment: Please post your relevant code here.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P7kce/2/

Answer (score 2):

That's because you use [`clear:both`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control), which enforces elements on the right to stay below elements on the left and vice versa. Use only `clear:left;float:left;` on odd elements and `clear:right; float:right;` on even elements ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/P7kce/3/)).

Also you have to use `float` on **both** even and odd elements. [`float`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position) will make following content flow on the opposite side, so if you apply `float` only even *or* odd elements you will get spaces again.

Comment: I've add: 

#timeline li:nth-of-type(odd){
    clear: right;float:right;
}
#timeline li:nth-of-type(even){
    clear: left;float:left;
}

and there is still gaps and now the line in middle is missing :/

Comment: Now it looks like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28372149/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-28%20at%2011.05.19%20PM.png

and:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28372149/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-28%20at%2011.05.12%20PM.png

Comment: @DavidRynes: For the middle line you need to add `<li style="float:none;clear:both;"></li>` as last element to the list. Also you should color the gaps you don't want in your original post.

Comment: Okay line is good :) but now:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28372149/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-28%20at%2011.12.17%20PM.png

and I cant open that example link :(

Comment: @DavidRynes: You should add those to your original question.

Comment: OK, I replaced it. It's better now, but not complete :( I'm lost with it.

Comment: Zeta did you think you can help me? Pretty good results I have with your solutions, but still few gasps are there :/

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with pure css (cross-browser compatibile). You need to use JS and recalculate absolute positions of all li elements. Maybe this article [Three Super Easy Ways to Pull Off a Masonry Layout](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/) can help.

Comment: So why its on some places good and continous and some spaces have big space between them and it looks good now. It's nearly done with Zeta's help, but still some minor gasps :/